# referring a control inside a component in flex

Tags: flex3, air

I am getting problem in accessing the control inside a component. The scenario is I have a datagrid in which I have a component in which I have a textarea. Now by selecting a menu option I need to focus the textarea.
Pls help me in referring the textarea. I need to setfocus in that textarea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: I want to perform edit functionality using menu options to the custom text component inside the grid. Each row have a custom text component. SO when I click on edit menu options, the appropriate edit operation should be performed on that particular custom text component.

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
myDataGrid.editedItemPosition = {rowIndex:4, columnIndex:1};
myDataGrid.editedItemRenderer.myTextArea.text = "blah";
```

That will probably only work if your component is set as the itemEditor and not the itemRenderer.